# Ender 3 v2 X limit switch not working sometimes

Tags: creality-ender-3, endstop

The limit switch of the x axis on my Ender 3 v2 is not working sometimes. The gantry hits the switch but the motor does not stop. Restarting the printer fixes the issue and prints normally. Next time you restart the printer the problem reappears.
I have changed the switch and the cables with brand new and the problem still remains.
This problem occurs 8/10 times I print and always goes away with restarting.